# Pivot Table Group By Day - 7 DAYS - How do I ensure that my LATEST DATES have 7 days?

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

Due to different data dates, in many instances the latest data does not have 7 days in them. How can I ensure that when I do a pivot table grouping, the latest data has 7 days in them instead of the earliest data?

[image]

Tried adjust the starting date but it is very tedious as it changes all the time as the data is constantly updated